# How to upload sqlite db before APK Upgrade?

Tags: cordova

I want to upload my sqlite db before anybody doing the APK upgrade from play-store.

Step 1 : User tries to take upgrade.

Step 2 : Before upgrade starts (upload local sqlite database)

Step 3 : Start APK upgrade

Can any body suggest me any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that you need to replace the database that's currently part of the application (and APK) with a new version then the only way to do this is to change the name of the database in the new version of the application.

The reason for this is that the sqlite plugin only looks in the directory structure created by the APK update if the database does not already exist locally. This seems really weird at first but actually makes sense in a way - if you're using a database to store user information then you don't want it overwritten by a blank version on the first update.